# Exclude Current year posts from query_post In wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to exclude curent year post from query_post.

query_posts( array('orderby'=>'rand',"paged"=>$paged,"year__not_in"=>array('2013')));

Comment: Take a look at the wordpress codereference (codex).

Comment: Oh and let's try to guess what your question is.

Comment: Charlotte Dunois i think my question is clear. And there is nothing regarding this in codex. That is why i am posting here.

Comment: I only see "I want to exclude current year post from query_post". So where is your question? Thats not a question, that's a statement what you want, it says not where you're running into problems or what your question is.

Comment: If you know how to exclude curent year post from query_post answer it. Otherwise don't waste my time and yours.

Comment: Actually there is in the codex :http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't exclude a year, you would instead include all other years.

To query everything apart from the current year, would look like the following...

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => date('Y'),
                'month' => 1,
                'day'   => 1,
            ),
            'inclusive' => false,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. Can you also tell me about the month. If i want all the posts but not the current month (eg Right now it is august so the post from august 2013,2012.... will not be included).

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs for date_query within wp_query

Comment: I checked but i can't understand. If you know please let me know.